# declare nfc variables as global options

Tags: c, lib-nfc

am working with the libnfc open source libraries in C, and am trying to declare the variables needed to initialize nfc in global mode i.e.

```
nfc_device *pnd;
nfc_target nt;
nfc_context *context;
nfc_init(&context);
```

all outside any function so that they are global, but am getting the following error:

```
error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '&' token
    extern nfc_init(&context);
                    ^
```

what could be the problem?

EDIT:
by the way, they work perfectly when declared within the main method

Comment: Did you mention `extern` before declaration..?

Comment: @ANBU.SANKAR that is not the reason from the error message. probably some missing header file containing the declaration of `nfc_context` `nfc_init()`. Also, please note `nfc_init(&context);` is a fucntion call, not a forward declaration.

Comment: Yes I did, tried both with and without the 'extern', but it still brought up the same error

Comment: I think , this is function declaration. Is it..?

Comment: `nfc_init` is function call, it cannot be used in a global scope, only inside some function.

Comment: @Alex Farber, your suggestion works, I put the 'nfc_init()' call inside the main function and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by putting the 'nfc_init(&context)' call inside the main function, without the EXTERN keyword